# Determine "Mode" for Highest Randomized Number

Tags: random, turing-lang

I am working on a Turing application that displays a random number, and then displays how many times that number is rolled, but then finds the mode, the highest value of the amount of times the random is rolled, and displays which number (1-6) is rolled the most. Thanks for the help.

```
var numberDice : int
var freq : array 1 .. 6 of int
var highestNum : int

highestNum := 0

for j : 1 .. 6
    freq (j) := 0
end for


for i : 1 .. 25
    randint (numberDice, 1, 6)

    freq (numberDice) := freq (numberDice) + 1


end for

for counter : 1 .. 6
    if freq (counter) > highestNum then
        highestNum := freq (counter)
    end if
end for


put "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

put "Number             Frequency"
put "1                  ", freq (1)
put "2                  ", freq (2)
put "3                  ", freq (3)
put "4                  ", freq (4)
put "5                  ", freq (5)
put "6                  ", freq (6)

put " "
put "Mode: ", highestNum
put "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Also, "mode" generally means something different from how you're using it here.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker My Question : I have found the highest number, but how can I apply that to the number (1-6)?

Comment: I still don't understand what that means.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is a rolling dice game, and I found the frequency of each dice, I need to say which is the highest rolled number

Comment: Yeah, and that's exactly what the program does. So what's the question?

Comment: Yes, but I need to say, the highest number is one if the numbers between 1 and 6, and display the "Mode" as a number form one through six

Comment: Ah, I get it now (although you're still using the word "Mode" oddly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional variable to hold the die you found to be highest:

```
var highestNum : int
var highestIndex : int

highestNum := 0
highestIndex := 0

. . .

    highestNum := freq (counter)
    highestIndex := counter
```

Answer (score 1):

It's great that people are still using Turing.  It is the best beginner's language hands down.

Your current code captures the maximum frequency *value*.  You also want to capture the *index of the maximum frequency value*.  Look carefully at your code to decide where the index value you need can be or is being computed.  Declare a variable to capture it, say `highestIndex`.  Then add code to do the capturing and printing.  I think it will take 3 lines.  What are they?  Where do they go?  When you understand how the current program works, you will see...